# LoadError occurs apparently at random

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Occasionally I get this error:

> LoadError: Expected /app/lib/services/foo/errors/login_failed.rb
>   to define Errors::LoginFailed

The error occurs in file `/lib/services/dvr_providers/website/bar.rb`:

```
module Services
  module Foo
    module Website
      class Bar < Base

        def some_method
          raise Errors::LoginFailed.new(some_param) if cannot_log_in
```

The file `/lib/services/foo/errors/login_failed.rb` contains:

```
module Services
  module Foo
    module Errors
      class LoginFailed < StandardError
```

I cannot replicate this in development. I have also verified that the code usually runs without error in production.

Notice that Rails is trying to resolve to `/app/lib`. I should mention that I have two other files named `login_failed.rb` in two different subfolders under `app\models`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is often causes by the autoloader when it runs in circles, trying to load classes with dependencies. Depending on where the autoload chain starts, this can sometimes fail. Consider this example:

```
# base.rb
class Base
  self.set_thing(opts)
    # do it
  end

  set_thing MyStuff::BAZ
end

# foo.rb
class Foo < Base
  STUFF = "things"

  set_thing MyStuff::FOOBAR
end

# my_stuff.rb
module MyStuff
  FOOBAR = "foobar"
  BAZ = "baz"

  def self.doit(something)
    # DO IT
  end

  doit Foo::STUFF
end
```

Here you have a circular dependency between constants. When loading the classes, Rails tries to automatically load the respective source files to resolve the constants.

If you first load `Base`, then everything should work fine. It should start to create the `Base` class, then `MyStuff` and from that `Foo`.

However, if you start with `Foo`, it requires `Base` which in turn requires `MyStuff` which in itself requires something from `Foo` which is not loaded yet. Thus, the Autoloader can not fully resolve the load queue and aborts.

To mitigate this issue, you can try to break dependency cycles by moving constant lookup into a later stage, e.g. by using blocks or methods for lazy evaluation instead of declaring things directly in the class.

Comment: Thanks; this is very instructive, but I don't think it's my problem. The class LoginFailed does nothing except call super in the initializer passing in a string composed from a string parameter.